# ASP.NET MVC forces an AJAX request be redirected to the login page when the FormsLogin session is no longer active

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, session, forms-authentication

I have some AJAX calls that render PartialViewResults via the jQuery.AJAX method. This works great, I get my views rendered exactly the way I want.

The problem arises when I leave the page up for a while and the Forms auth session expires. When I click an action that performs an AJAX request, it shows the login page in my div.

I want it to redirect the WHOLE page to the login page.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set it up in the Application_EndRequest() method of the Global.asax

You can check to see if the request is an ajax request and also check if it is sending an HTTP redirect (302) if it is, then we actuall want to send a 401.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest() {
            var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
            // If we're an ajax request, and doing a 302, then we actually need to do a 401
            if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && context.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
                Context.Response.Clear();
                Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            }
        }
```

Then in your client code, in a globally accessible area:

```
MyNamespace.handleAjaxError = function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 401) {
        // perform a redirect to the login page since we're no longer authorized
        window.location.replace("logout path");
    }    
    } else {
        MyNamespace.displayGeneralError();
    }
};

  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: userAdmin.addUserActionUrl,
  success: userAdmin.createUserEditorDialog,
  error: MyNamespace.handleAjaxError
 });
```

Comment: If you want to do this for ALL ajax requests on your page (useful on a single page ajax app) take a look at http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: This kills the ability to use RedirectToAction() inside an action called via ajax. I had this code implemented and needed to remove it because RedirectToAction() sends a valid 302 as well.

Comment: @JasonButera Not sure if this is still interesting to you, but I have found a way to circumvent it with newer versions of ASP.NET MVC. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With current versions of ASP.NET MVC there is a much easier solution to fix this issue: `Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`.

You can apply this in your `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContextWrapper context = new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context);

    if (context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        context.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it with this. And then when the user was unauthorized, i returned a string with Content() back. And the ajax call back redirected then the user to the login with window.location = "loginpath"

Answer (score 0):

When I have FormsAuthentication in place, I will include the Login URL in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3431350/1559213 provided by @Chris Kooken

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {

        var context = new HttpContextWrapper(Context);
        // If we're an ajax request, and doing a 302, then we actually need to do a 401
        if (Context.Response.StatusCode == 302 && context.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && 
            Context.Response.RedirectLocation.Contains(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl))
        {
            Context.Response.Clear();
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
    }
```