# RedirectToAction to PartialView from Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am calling an action method from a `Ajax.ActionLink` as follow:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("By Biggest price"), "CatSearch",
    new { sortBy = "PriceBiggest" },
    new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", OnBegin = "$('#ajaxReplace').hide();", OnComplete = "$('#ajaxReplace').show();", LoadingElementId = "busyDiv", UpdateTargetId = "ajaxReplace" },
    new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-warning boxShadow", @style = "margin-top: 5px;" })
```

This part works fine! Since my `ProductController` has an `[Authorize]` attribute well the user is redirected to the login page and its alright also. Post/After a success login I want to redirect to my Controller Action (same url as before login that was rendered by the `ajax.actionlink`)

The action returns a `PartialView` using but the problem is that when I redirect to the `PartialView` it doesn't inherit the _Layout page most probably because it wasn't called from the parent.

I am not sure how to approach. I am sure there's something very easy and simple. I tried few things like `window.location/javascript`.. If only I could simulate after the success login the same call as the `ajax.actionlink`! :(

Any ideas, help please?

Comment: AJAX is usually used when you _don't_ want to navigate away from the page. Redirect result is not followed by AJAX so you must use client-side JavaScript to do the navigation yourself.

Comment: From my AccountController Login action, what should I return exactly? a Javascript ActionResult? any examples?

Comment: Maybe a better question would be, Is it possible to return a Json action result without calling the action from a AjaxLink, Jquery, javascript or Ajax beginform? if yes, how to link the Json result to the view, ex would be appreciated?

Comment: i came across this example BUT the redirection should simulate an Ajax.Actionlink and the sample code will not call async/ajax way.

CODE

return Json(new 
{ 
    redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home",e), 
    isRedirect = true 
});

success: function(json) {
    if (json.isRedirect) {
        window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
    }
}

Comment: There are several answers that may help you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5258721/2030565), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20888316/2030565), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7975311/2030565), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/199099/2030565).  When you return a JSON result to AJAX you'd usually have the client-side script build a view or act on the data to perform some logic. Your last comment performs logic with the JSON response (and I don't see why it isn't asynchronous).