# MVC Identity Checking Authentication on Razor Layout View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, identity

I am using ASP.Net Identity on my web application that shares the same Layout page for all views.

I am using the approach below to redirect non authenticated users to the login page instead of adding the `[Authorize]` attribute on my controllers.
This code is in the Razor Layout View:

```
@using IdentityManager
@{ 
    if (!Helper.IfUserAuthenticated())
    {
        Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Login"));
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
. . . . . . .
```

The above approach works as intended. What I want to know if this approach is wrong or not recommended.

Thank you

Comment: Instead of prepare method if possible create a property like `IsAuthenticate`

Comment: @jishansiddique what do you mean by property? How should i do it?

Comment: Like `if(!Helper.IsAuthenticate)`

Comment: @jishansiddique you mean an indirect call to the `Identity` object?

Comment: No not like that you can create one boolean property instead of method and just check in the layout page.

Comment: I don't think changing from a method call to a property call changes much here, it seems a bit outside of the question. @onhax, this question seems very opinion based which doesn't work well on SO. Is there something wrong with your current approach and why not use `[Authorize]`? If it works for you that should be good enough

Comment: @Xerillio i see. Pondering upon it, I realized that my approach won't redirect ajax calls to the login page even if `[Authorize]` is present in all controllers. I think i had to implement a custom authorize atrribute specifically for ajax calls. Thank you for the insight

Comment: @onhax I see. Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3431350/3034273) will help you with that problem